# Replacing values within list elements

Tags: r

I have the following two lists:

```
list1 <- list(c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1), c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0), c(0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1))
list2 <- list(c(9, 10, 11, 12, 13), c(5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13), c(1, 2, 3, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13))
```

`list2` represents positions in `list1` that I would like to convert to `0`. In other words, I would like the 9th, 10th, 11th, 12th, and 13th values in the first element of `list1` to be `0`; I would like the 5th through 13th values in the second element of `list1` to be `0`; etc. The resulting list should be the following:

```
list3 <- list(c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), c(1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), c(0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0))
```

How can I do this? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

We can do this with `purrr::map2` from the `tidyverse`:

```r
list1 <- list(c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1), c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0), c(0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1))
list2 <- list(c(9, 10, 11, 12, 13), c(5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13), c(1, 2, 3, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13))

library(purrr)
map2(
  .x = list1,
  .y = list2,
  .f = function(list, indexes){
    list[indexes] <- 0
    list
  }
)
#> [[1]]
#>  [1] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0
#> 
#> [[2]]
#>  [1] 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
#> 
#> [[3]]
#>  [1] 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

Created on 2018-10-22 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).

Answer (score 2):

Here is a quick and dirty method using a `for` loop:

```
for(i in 1:length(list1)){
  list1[[i]][list2[[i]]]<-0
}
```

I am sure someone can improve on this using a lapply or a function from purrr.

Comment: How would you do this with the `lapply` function?

Comment: @DavidMoore See my updated solution for an implementation of `mapply`

Answer (score 1):

Using a simple loop in base R,

```
for(i in 1:length(list1)) {
   list1[[i]][list2[[i]]] <- 0
}

> list1
[[1]]
 [1] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0

[[2]]
 [1] 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0

[[3]]
 [1] 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

You could also do it with an `mapply()` like below, with the `SIMPLIFY=F` forcing the function to return in list form.

```
funfun <- function(x, y, recode=0) {
   x[y] <- recode
   return(x)
}

mapply(list1, list2, FUN=funfun, SIMPLIFY=F)
[[1]]
 [1] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0

[[2]]
 [1] 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0

[[3]]
 [1] 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0
```